# C# HttpListener total failure on SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, https, mono, httplistener

Ok, if i'm running this simplified code snippet the program crashes violently and doesn't even throw an exception.

So here is what i've done beforehand:

- created ssl certificate
- bound it to port 8443
- validated with 'httpcfg -list'
- was making sure that '8443.cer' and '8443.pkv' are in 'user/.config/.mono/httplistener'

so everything should work right? false! this is driving me insane for hours now..

```js
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

public class HttpListenerTest {

 public static void Main(string[] args) {

  Console.WriteLine("Initialize..");
  HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
  listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8089/");
  listener.Prefixes.Add("https://*:8443/");
  listener.Start();

  while (true) {
   Console.WriteLine("Listening..");
   HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();

   Console.WriteLine("Respond..");
   byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("works!");
   context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
   context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
   context.Response.Close();
  }
 }
}
```

if i run this code and make a http request on port 8089 everything is fine. A https request on 8443 kills the process and the only thing witch happens is an 'unusual event' (
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi9B1.png)
) in debug mode.

..googled the missing filename, got 4 unrelated results.

I'm at the end of my knowledge and really need ssl to work with the listener.

So if you have any experience with this or suggestions, please tell me.

Comment: What version of mono? and are you enabling boringssl?

Comment: 1. Mono 5.2.0.224 (d15-3/14f2c81) (64-bit) 2. have to investigate real quick

Comment: I guess i can't enable it with a console project. ( xamarin and visual studio for mac)

Comment: Within the IDE, set an env. variable via a Run Configuration (MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=btls), if you are running from a shell, just export the env. var or pass it on the same line as your mono cmd

Comment: ok i hope i did this correct [screenshot](https://ibb.co/cwuxuQ) but unfortunately it didn't change anything

Comment: tried to pass it with the cmd (mono servertest.exe MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=btls), but also no effect

Comment: `MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=btls mono servertest.exe`

Comment: Don't use HTTPS with Mono, it fails miserably, just put an NGINX or HAProxy before it which manages SSL and sends HTTP requests to the Mono server, it will work flawlessly and a lot faster.

Comment: @SushiHangover YOU ARE A GENIUS!! IT WORKS! you just saved me hours of pain i can't thank you enough :D

Comment: @Gusman you where right. It only works on localhost, if i want to run it on the server it fails. Do you have any starting point for me how to put NGINX before the Mono server?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/145383/proxy-https-requests-to-a-http-backend-with-nginx

Comment: I've been using this solution in production servers for more than 5 years and it works wonderfully, even in the case you get in some way Mono to work with SSL, with this method you will be able to serve a lot more requests with a lot less resource usage, mono SSL implementation is very buggy and slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 2 Solutions for this problem:

**If you need a quick fix for localhost (Just for localhost)**

Thanks to SushiHangovers comment, setting the missing environment variable 'MONO_TLS_PROVIDER' to 'btls' (BoringSSL) fixed the problem.

```
$ MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=btls mono servertest.exe
```

**If you need it to work on a server**

Thanks to Gusman here is a short and simple to follow guide on how to use Nginx for managing SSL and sending Http requests to the Mono server.

**1.** First install/setup Nginx

www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

**2.** Then install Certbot

certbot.eff.org

**3.** And secure Nginx with Certbot

www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

**4.** Reverse proxy to your HttpListener port  ([taken from here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-buildbot-with-ssl-using-an-nginx-reverse-proxy))

**4.1** Open the Nginx configfile

```
 $ sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

**4.2** Comment out the default try_files line and specify the Reverse proxy settings

```
 . . .
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

                # Reverse proxy settings
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8010;
             }
. . .
```

And change

```
server_name _;
```

to

```
server_name example.com www.example.com;
```

Now you should be good to go.